# How to get Parent and Child Table data as a single query in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get all data from 2 table based on `userID=user1`
from parent and child table as i shown in below image 
[image]

Comment: Are you using all those sql-server versions?

Comment: Search for recursive CTE

Comment: @HoneyBadger : what is recursive CTE any link can you provide

Comment: You could try Google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT      parent.CommentID as CommentID,
            parent.userID as userID, 
            parent.Message as Message,
            parent.Date as date,
            NULL as ParentCommentID
FROM        #ParentComment parent
WHERE       UserID = 'user1'

UNION

SELECT      child.c_commentID as CommentID,
            child.c_userID as userID, 
            child.c_message as Message,
            child.c_Date as date,
            child.c_parentcommentID as ParentCommentID
FROM        #ChildComment child
WHERE       child.c_userID = 'user1'
```

Here's an SQL fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bb46/2

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: @user6503334 Glad to help. This is simple as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use Join

Inner join if the id always match

```
 select 
   a.CommentID as CommentI
   ,a.userID, as userID
   , a.Message as Message
   , a.Date as date
   , b.c_commentID as parent__comment_id 
  from parent_comment as a
 inner join child_comment as b  on a.commentID = b.c_commentID
```

left join if not always match

```
 select 
   a.CommentID as CommentI
   ,a.userID, as userID
   , a.Message as Message
   , a.Date as date
   , b.c_commentID as parent__comment_id 
  from parent_comment as a
 left join child_comment as b  on a.commentID = b.c_commentID
```

Comment: but it will display like this commentID, userID, Message, Date, c_commentID, c_userID, c_Message, c_Date, c_ParentcommentID

Comment: And what's the problem .. if you need only some column .. set the columns name you need .

Answer (score 0):

Just use Left join with union like this example

```
Select TP.* 
  FROM ParentTable as TP LEFT JOIN ChildTable as TC 
  ON TC.c_ParentcommentID = TP.commentID AND TC.c_ParentcommentID = null 
  WHERE TP.userID='user1'
UNION ALL 
Select TC.c_CommnetID as CommentID , TC.c_userID  as userID , TC.c_Message as Message , TC.Date as 'Date'
  FROM ChildTable as TC  inner join ParentTable as TP 
  ON  TC.c_ParentcommentID = TP.commentID
  WHERE TC.userID='user1'
```